# How to return null guid

Tags: c#-4.0

How i can return null in guid instead returning Guid.empty. 
here is the code:

```
ConsumerID = (subList == null ? Guid.Empty : subList.ConsumerID)
```

Thank you

Comment: Also, if this if for a database insert, you could use DBNull.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) type is a `struct`, so it cannot have a `Null` value.

Use [`System.Nullable<Guid>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) instead, or the even better, `Guid?`.

```
var guid = (Guid?)null;
```

Answer (score -1):

return new Guid[0] will retuen new empty array of type uuid